# Need an ERD of the schema mentioned

Tags: database-design, schema, erd, system-databases, management

Need the erd of the schema for doctor, patient and appointment database. scenario is given as under:

## Clinic Management Entity-Relationship Model

-Doctor has a unique id, name, address, qualification and speciality stored for him. Doctor can have 3 time slots in which he can check patients on each day and specialists are not available daily but twice a week only. however, medical officers are available daily.
-Patient has unique cnic, name, address and has a home phone and mobile number, blood group stored
-Disease data is maintained for more than 300 diseases with disease id, scientific name, common symptoms.
-When patient comes to clinic 5 common diseases out of 300 are noted for each patient in (yes or no) response i.e: bloodpresure, diabetes, uric acid, heart attack, hepatitis.
-Patient can book appointment from many doctors at different time slots. A doctor can give appointment to only 10 patients in a time slot. Appointment is not given for doctor if his time slot reaches full capacity for that particular day.

Comment: Screaming urgent will just get your question ignored. What have you tried? Do you have a specific question (rather than design this for me)? This isn't a free homework site. Its for helping only.

Comment: Low effort answer: https://lmgtfy.com/?q=Clinic+Management+Entity-Relationship+Model

Comment: @SirSwears-a-lot Thank you! I only needed something to relate to complete my query that's why i just wrote the whole damn thing here in urgency. Thank you, this helped me!

Comment: Another low effort answer: http://databaseanswers.org/data_models/hospital_management/index.htm